# Config Version Control to manage multiple files separately

Tags: git, svn, version-control, cvs

I have a problem to keep track of spread configurations files that may be changed by users or new releases.

I want to auto-merge changes, failed merges will be discarded and might be merged by a person, but they may be forgotten.
New releases should attempt handle forgotten manual merges.

I have thought a way to do it, and I need to keep track of different versions, place labels and merge each single file.
I want to apply "user-mod", "released<#>", "auto-merged<#>", "manual-merged<#>" labels on single files that will allow me to monitor them and work the auto-merge process on them.

CVS would let me do that easily per file, however it seems that is obsolete and not maintained.
SVN and GIT keep track of the whole set of files and treat the whole as a single version.

Is there a way to manage each file that way without cvs or placing each file in its own repo?

Comment: In svn, git, etc. nothing *prevents* you from committing one file's changes at a time; that's just not the "normal" use-case. What problem do you foresee using these tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can use svn properties on each file: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.properties.html

Say, use 'custom:merge-status' property with desired values (user-mod, releasedX ...). Then you can analyze these statuses from script or manually.